# Show values in disabled selectfiled on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I am using Sencha touch 2 to create a disabled selectfield, populated with default value. The problem is that if I disable the selectfield, then the value is not shown on iOS devices(it is blank and disabled)., but the value is shown properly on other platforms (android,chrome browser). How can I make the value visible? Here's my code for the selectfield.

```
xtype: 'selectfield',
disabled: true,
id: 'lengthUnit',
label: 'Length unit',
labelWidth: '35%',
labelWrap: true,
name: 'lengthUnit',
options: [
{
text: 'km',
value: 'km'
},
{
text: 'mi',
value: 'mi'
}
```

The value is set by calling setRecord function on the parent container. The values populate properly if the selectfield is not disabled. This problem occurs only on iOS devices!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `readOnly: true` instead of `disabled: true`.

If you want it to look like it's disabled then add: `cls: 'x-item-disabled'`

If you are trying to set values or read values from a field is always a good idea not to disable it.

Comment: This works! but any idea why the disabled controls don't show values on ios? Should I raise a bug about this with Sencha?

Comment: I think you should test this with the latest version (nightly builds) if you have access and see if this problem still occurs. If yes, open up a bug with Sencha, because if this was the intended behavior, it should act the same way in every browser/OS.

Comment: changed setDisabled(True); to setReadOnly(True) in iOS field was now visible. Thanks